# Doctrine paginator count is not correct

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Symfony project I have a `User` entity with the following properties to define followers relation

```
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: self::class, inversedBy: 'followers')]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: "follows")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "follower_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: "followed_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
    private $followedUsers;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: self::class, mappedBy: 'followedUsers')]
    private $followers;
```

I am attempting to get the paginated list of a User's followers with the following query in my `UserRepository`

```
    public function getPaginatedFollowersByUser(User $user, int $offset, int $limit): Paginator
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u')
            ->innerJoin('u.followers', 'f')
            ->andWhere('f.id = :userId')
            ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        $paginator = new Paginator($qb, true);
        return $paginator;
    }
```

where Paginator is an instance of `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator`.

This works fine and now I want to know how many items are there in the result. In the DB there is only 1 follower defined for the user I am querying, yet `$paginator->count()` and `count($paginator)` both return the value `2`. When I iterate the paginator I find only 1 result, as expected.

I am not sure what I am missing or doing wrong. Is the counting of the result done in a different way?

Thank you!

NOTE: The workaround I've found so far is to use

```
$count = count($paginatedUsers->getIterator()->getArrayCopy());
```

instead of

```
$count = count($paginatedUsers);
```

It is not very elegant but it does output the expected `1`.

Comment: does `$paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(null)` change sth. ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like changing anything; I've tried `count($paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(null))` and `$paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(null)->count()` and both still return `2`

Comment: I am embarrassed, but I'm not sure that your query does what you said. It looks like you aren't counting the numbers of followers of the user provided in params. It looks like you are counting the numbers of users that follows the user provided in params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am embarrassed to say that the paginator was working perfectly fine and it was my mistake that this failed.

The DB in fact had 2 entries corresponding to this query, meaning that the result given by the paginator was in fact correct. The `$offset` parameter in my query was `1` instead of the `0` that I expected, which made the first element be ignored and therefore my iterator only found 1 result but there were 2 results for the query.